# How to set multiple default values for a multivalue parameter in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a multivalue parameter that is populated from a query that returns an Id (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) column and a Label (VARCHAR) column. I set the parameter to have a Text type, to use Id as the **Value field** and Label as the **Label field** and it works fine.

Now I want to set a few default values so that when the report is run, these values will be checked by default. In the **Default Values** tab, I have tried entering the Id values without quotes, with single quotes, and with double quotes, as well as trying the Label values without quotes, with single quotes, and with double quotes. However, in all cases none of the items are checked with I run the report.

I do not want to **Get values from a query**, I want to **Specify values**. How can I make this work?

Comment: Try converting Id to string in the query that populates parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also ran into this problem, specifying default values to a Unique identifier is not supported (I cannot find any source to back this up, just my own experience).

Is there a specific reason why you cannot use **Get values from a query**?

The solution user1578107 addresses will also work, use a convert to pass a varchar(36) to your 
 parameter:

```
select convert(varchar(36),Id)
from table
```

Comment: I probably could use Get values from a query, but I want to be able to change the defaults in the RDL and not have to change a stored procedure or view.

Changing the stored procedure that I use as the datasource for the multivalue parameter to return a CHAR(36) instead of the native UNIQUEIDENTIFIER allowed me to set the defaults as I wished, using the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER values (without quotes).

Thanks!